# Why am I getting connection refused with IP address even though it works with localhost and firewall is open?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, ufw

When I run `sudo ufw status` on a Ubuntu box, I get the following output

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
30303                      ALLOW       Anywhere
9000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
3000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
8008/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
8008                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30303 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8008/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8008 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

When I access a service running on port `8008` from within the box using `localhost` it works. That is, the following works:

```
curl --head http://localhost:8008/metrics
```

But if I use the IP address of the box instead, it does not work. That is:

```
$ curl --head http://<public-ip>:8008/metrics
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <public-ip> port 8008: Connection refused
```

And If I also try accessing from the browser, it is still connection refused.

What could be going on here? The output of `sudo ufw status` shows that the port is open and accessible, but it is still not working.

Edit:
As requested in the comments:

```
netstat -tln | grep 8008
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8008          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

```
ss -tln | grep 8008
LISTEN  0        511            127.0.0.1:8008           0.0.0.0:*
```

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -tln | grep 8008` (or `ss` instead of `netstat` if the `netstat` command isn't available).

Comment: Is the service bound to 127.0.0.1 or `localhost`, or to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Is your system behind a NAT that is mapping a public IP address to a private IP address? If so the system performing the NAT may have a firewall as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the output of `netstat`. You are listening on address`127.0.0.1`. You probably need to listen on `0.0.0.0` (all local interfaces/addresses).

Thanks to the other commenters for working it out.